# Why does this code fail when using == but work using <=?

Tags: java, operators

I just started to learn programming with a course at futurelearn.com.

I have a bitmap and a ball. The task is to code boundaries for the x-direction.

The working code looks like this:

```
if ((mBallX <= mBall.getWidth()/2 && mBallSpeedX < 0) || (mBallX >= mCanvasWidth - mBall.getWidth()/2 && mBallSpeedX > 0)){
        mBallSpeedX = -mBallSpeedX;
```

But i have a logical problem. I want to understand why i cant use "==" instead of "<=". When I do so, the ball flies out of the right side of the screen.

Here is a video for understandig. It should contain all perhaps missing information.:

https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/begin-programming/7/steps/42942

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the ball is not moving continuously - you're moving it in discrete steps of some fixed size. As a result, it's extremely unlikely that the ball would *exactly* end up at one end of the screen or the other. Rather, it's more likely that it accidentally overshoots one side of the screen by some tiny amount. If you check to see if the ball is *exactly* at the side of the screen, you won't properly account for these cases. On the other hand, if you ask whether the ball has *moved past* the sides of the screen, then you will correctly account for these cases.

Comment: Thank you for your fast Help :) I understand it now :)